# How to paint ABS to look like wood

Tags: abs, post-processing, color

I have a piece printed in white ABS, which is a half-scale replica of an unvarnished oak sculpture. After sanding off the worst of the layer lines, I'd like to paint it to get a nice wood finish. I believe that most hobby paints should stick fine, but how should I paint it to get a nice oaky appearance? Should I do layers of different colours? Will I get better results with spray or brush paints?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is unrelated to 3D printing.

Comment: The artistic methods used to create artificial "wood grain" patterns on plastic objects are reasonably well-published, albeit not in 3D printing forums.  I would look around various "art" or "home crafts"  or "furniture finishing"  websites for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [step-by-step instructions on Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Model-Making-From-ABS-to-Ceramic-and-Wood/) specific to 3D-printed parts. In summary:

1. Sand and brush with acetone for a smooth finish (I guess the acetone vapour treatment would work as well.)
2. Prime with plastic primer
3. Spray-paint with a satin, nutmeg-coloured base coat
4. Add grain with darker, acrylic paint using a fine brush